# How can I permanently add a key to os.environ?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a Django deployment and have the following logic in my settings file.

```
if 'DEPLOYMENT_TYPE' in os.environ:
    DEPLOYMENT = os.environ['DEPLOYMENT_TYPE'].upper()
```

Thus, I want to be able to set the 'DEPLOYMENT_TYPE' key in os.environ on a per-computer basis.  I have tried in a separate shell:

```
os.putenv('DEPLOYMENT_TYPE', ...)
os.environ['DEPLOYMENT_TYPE'] = ...
```

However, these don't work because I'm guessing os.environ gets populated when os is imported.  Thus, what's the best way to set the 'DEPLOYMENT_TYPE' on a per-computer basis?  I can't just stick the line in my settings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `os.environ` is that it's initialized from the shell environment it's running in. So you should set it in the environment settings - ie `bash_profile` or whatever - of the user that's running the deployment.

Comment: Great, that makes a lot of sense!  What specifically would the line in bash_profile look like?

Comment: I tried to do that on a mac/django: set `DJANGO_DEBUG="True"` in `.bash_profile` then I ran `source ~/.bash_profile` then I started the runserver but I get `False` on `if os.environ.has_key("DJANGO_DEBUG"):` Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetEnv within Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) to handle this, assuming it only applies to your Django Web environment.